# laravel handling the OPTION http method request

Tags: php, cors, laravel

I am developing an **angularjs** app which uses **laravel** as its back end server.
I am having trouble accessing data from laravel since before each GET request, angular first sends an OPTION request as below.

```
OPTIONS /61028/index.php/api/categories HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3501
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, accept
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3501/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.5
```

I have tried to respond this by adding the following code in the before filter

```
if (Request::getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
    $headers = array(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, content-type'
    );
    return Response::make('', 200, $headers);
}
```

This creates a response with the headers:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 20
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=97
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-cache
access-control-allow-headers: X-Requested-With, content-type
```

Although the headers are set, the browser still throws an error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/61028/index.php/api/categories. Origin http://localhost:3501 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have also tried setting the allow origin to the origin presented in the request header as below

```
$origin=Request::header('origin');
//then within the headers
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' =>' '.$origin[0],
```

and still the same error
What am i doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

## Edit 1

I am currently using a very ugly hack where i over-ride laravels initialization when an OPTIONS request is received. This i have done in the index.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods : POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : X-Requested-With, content-type');
}else{
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @version  3.2.13
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 * @link     http://laravel.com
 */
```

I also had to add the allow-origin header to the before filter.

I know this is not smart but it is my only solution for now

Comment: I'm pretty sure when I tried this, I found out that some browsers require the casing to be correct. Looks like Laravel is lowercasing everything, which is technically OK, but may still fail.

Comment: @Evert i noticed that and considered using the in-built php `header()` function instead. However the issue is still persistent.

Comment: That is weird then. Are you also making sure you are sending back all these headers for the GET, PUT, DELETE and POST request? It is required..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is with reference to your question regarding the above issue. You did not mention the version of laravel and angularJS. I assume you are using lattest angularJS and Laravel. I also assume, the angular is hosted on **http://localhost:3501** and the laravel is hosted on **http://localhost**
Just follow the below steps.

- Put below code block in /public/.htaccess file of laravel

  ```
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3501"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
  ```
- Put below line in config of angular

  ```
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  ```

Never use ***** as wild card character. Larvel can not identify the domain for session management. So set **http://localhost:3501** as full domain name to **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.
I think these will help you.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug in Laravel that got recently [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1586). You may want to update to the latest revision.

Also, you need to enable CORS support for your server.

Comment: What does "you need to enable CORS support for your server" mean, though?

Comment: "Also, you need to enable CORS support for your server" — that doesn't make sense, that is what the question is trying to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

add this in your index.php file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```